# Is it possible to enable Spring context caching in Mule FunctionalTestCase?

Tags: spring, mule

I use FunctionalTestCase in order to test Mule ESB 3.5 application.

For testing I have a class which looks like:

```
public class MyIntegrationTest extends FunctionalTestCase {

    @Override
    protected String getConfigFile()
    {
        return "app-config.xml";
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception{
    }
    @Test
    public void test2() throws Exception{
    }
    ...
}
```

I noticed that every `@Test` method re-creates application context and tests are fairly slow.

With bare Spring framework simple integration test would cache application context so tests would be much faster. I was wondering is it possible to do Mule application integration testing with cached Spring application context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AbstractMuleContextTestCase` has `disposeContextPerClass` property. You need to set it to `true` in order to achieve context caching per test class. First I wasted some time trying to set it in `@Before` method but it is already too late.

I managed to enable context caching by using `disposeContextPerClass(true)` in test class constructor:

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class MyIntegrationTest extends FunctionalTestCase {
    public MyIntegrationTest() {
        setDisposeContextPerClass(true);
    }
}
```